# how to show data not found when ajax call codeigniter using select option

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

how to show data not found,
when ajax call data not found  using select option

```
          <div class="col-md-6 col-12">
             <div class="mb-1">
              <label class="form-label" for="country-floating"><?php echo display('city')?></label>
                 <select name="city" id="city" class="select2 form-select"  >
                    <option value="">No Selected</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
```

where my  ajax call function are as

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#state').change(function(){ 
             var id=$(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                url : "<?php echo base_url('suppliers/get_city');?>",
                method : "POST",
                data : {id: id},
                async : true,
                dataType : 'json',
                success: function(data){  
                    var html = '';
                    var i;
                    for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){
                        html += '<option value='+data[i].id+'>'+data[i].city_name+'</option>';
                    }
                    $('#city').html(html);
                },
               error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
              alert('Error: ' + textStatus + ' - ' + errorThrown);
               }
               });
            return false;
        }); 
                });
</script>
```

I don't understand anything now , please help

my code is working properly i just want to show that when no data is found then i want to show "**data not found**" in select option

Comment: Hi, please fix the formatting of your code.

Comment: what do you get, if you put a `console.dir(data)` in your success function and there is a result? And what do you get if there is no result?

Comment: @Vickel  my code is working properly i just want to show that when no data is found then i want to show "data not found" in select option

Comment: check if data exists: `if (!=data)`.... or `if(data.length==0)`

Comment: if (!=data){
                        var html = '';
                        var i;
                        for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){
                            html += '<option value='+data[i].id+'>'+data[i].state_name+'</option>';
                        }
                        $('#state').html(html);
     }else {
      html += '<option value='No State Found'</option>';
      $('#state').html(html);
     }

Comment: if you would edit your updated code inside your question (and would format the whole code to make it better readable), then you would see that you want to display option data when there is no data and the "no state found" when there is data. Also you need the variable definition html='' out of the if/else clause, otherwise you have an error in the else clause...